# How to Save batch users in laravel 8.0?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I created a form, where one can add or remove entries and save all entries at once.
Now the form only saves the last entry. Scripts to add and remove record, works pretty well.
How can i make sure all the entries are saved to the db. I have been looking for a solution but can't find any.

## Controller

```
`public function saveGroupDelegateData(Request $request ){
      foreach ($request -> (*.lastIndex) as $key => $lastIndex) {
       $SaveAttendees = Attendees::create([
      'title' => $request->title[$lastIndex],
       'name' => $request->name[$lastIndex],
       'email' => $request->email[$lastIndex],
       'company' => $request->company[$lastIndex],
       'phone_number' => $request->phone_number[$lastIndex],
       'job_title' => $request->job_title[$lastIndex],
       'event_role' => $request->event_role[$lastIndex],
       'tour' => $request->tour[$lastIndex],
       'tour_location' => $request->tour_location[$lastIndex]
        ]);
}}`
```

## Viewblade

```
`<form action="/SaveGroupAttendees" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
        <div id="inputFormRow" >
          <p style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">Attendee [1]</p> 
          <label>Email to share Invoice to</label><input type="text"  name="desired_mail" placeholder="Email to Share Invoice To" />
          <br>  <br> 
            <div class="input-group mb-3"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="Users.Index" value="1" />
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="title" name="title[1]">
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Full name" name="name[1]">
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="email" name="email[1]">
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="company" name="company[1]">
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="phone_number" name="phone_number[1]">
                    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="job_title" name="job_title[1]">
                    <input type="hidden" value="delegate" placeholder="event_role" name="event_role[1]">
                    <label for="tour[1]"  >Attend Excursion</label>
                      <select name="tour[1]" class="form-control round" id="tour" >
                      <option  value="yes">Yes</option>
                      <option active value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <label id="tour_location" for="tour_location[1]" >Exursion Location</label>
                    <select class="form-control round" id="tours" name="tour_location[1]">
                      <option value="None">Choose Location</option>
                      <option  value="kenya">Kenya</option>
                      <option  value="uganda">Uganda</option>
                    </select>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <!-- <button id="removeRow" type="button">
                       (-) Remove Attendee
                    </button> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  
  
    <div id="newRow"></div>
    <p>
        <button id="addRow" type="button">
            (+) Add Attendee
        </button>
    </p>
   
    <div class="text-center">         
       <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="{{ trans('global.save') }}">
     </div>
</form>
        </div>


        
      </div>
    </d iv>

 <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 

    // add row
  
let lastIndex= 2 ;
// add row
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div id="inputFormRow" class="table table-condensed table-striped">';
    html += '  <p style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">Attendee['+lastIndex+']</p>';
    html += '    <div class="input-group mb-3">';
    html += '  <input type="text"required="required"  placeholder="title" name="title['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += '  <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Full Name" name="name['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += '  <input type="text"  required="required" placeholder="Email" name="email['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += '  <input type="text"  required="required" placeholder="Company" name="company['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += ' <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone_number['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += '  <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Job title" name="job_title['+lastIndex+']"';
    html += '        <input type="hidden" value="delegate" placeholder="event_role" name="event_role['+lastIndex+']">';
    html += '        <label  for="tour['+lastIndex+']">Attend Excursion?</label> <select class="form-control round" id="tour" name="tour['+lastIndex+']"><option  value="yes">Yes</option><option active value="no">No</option></select>';
    html += '        <label for="tour_location['+lastIndex+']">Excursion Location</label><select class="form-control round" name="tour_location['+lastIndex+']" id="tours"><option active value="None" >Choose Location</option><option  value="KE">Kenya</option><option  value="Uganda">Uganda</option></select>';
    html += '        <div class="input-group-append">';
    html += '            <button id="removeRow" type="button">';
    html += '                (-) Remove Attendee';
    html += '            </button>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '</div>';
    lastIndex=lastIndex+1;
    $('#newRow').append(html);
});`

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    lastIndex=lastIndex-1;
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? It’s pretty obvious it only saves the last entry because you explicitly told it to do so.

Comment: `$request -> (*.lastIndex)` - what kind of PHP syntax is that?

Comment: @dbf, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

i think you can change the name of the input element. you can change it to this:

```
<input type="text" required="required" placeholder="title" name="data[lastIndex][title]">
```

and in controller you can looping the data.

```
foreach($request->data as $value) {
   Attendees::create([
      'title' => $value['title']
   ]);
}
```